# How to parse .dat file without repeated structures

Tags: python, matlab, parsing, numpy

My question is about parsing the output of Missile Datcom, I don't know if someone knows it. The length of the file is variable.

My aim is to retrieve all the data stored in those tables and save it in a correct file structure (I think MATLAB .mat file). The only symmetry I can get is the repetition of text structures like this:

```
***** THE USAF AUTOMATED MISSILE DATCOM * REV 3/99 *****     CASE   1
           AERODYNAMIC METHODS FOR MISSILE CONFIGURATIONS          PAGE   2
               STATIC AERODYNAMICS FOR BODY-FIN SET 1

   ******* FLIGHT CONDITIONS AND REFERENCE QUANTITIES *******
 MACH NO  =       0.01                REYNOLDS NO = 2.318E+05 /M
 ALTITUDE =        0.0 M         DYNAMIC PRESSURE =      7.09 N/M**2
 SIDESLIP =      -5.00 DEG                   ROLL =      0.00 DEG     
 REF AREA =      0.006 M**2         MOMENT CENTER =     1.750 M
 REF LENGTH =     0.10 M           LAT REF LENGTH =      0.10 M

               ----- LONGITUDINAL -----     -- LATERAL DIRECTIONAL --
     ALPHA       CN        CM        CA        CY       CLN       CLL

    -15.00   -13.959    -4.106     2.661     4.031     1.817     0.565
    -12.50   -12.292    -1.954     5.103     4.302     1.267     0.449
    -10.00    -9.985    -0.720     7.148     4.600     0.677     0.253
     -7.50    -7.477    -0.030     7.516     4.833     0.143     0.073
     -5.00    -4.881     0.206     6.380     4.881    -0.206     0.000
     -2.50    -2.374     0.167     5.504     4.949    -0.509    -0.059
     -1.00    -0.933     0.069     5.287     4.965    -0.604    -0.036
      0.00     0.000     0.000     5.308     4.967    -0.623    -0.000
      1.00     0.933    -0.069     5.287     4.965    -0.604     0.036
      2.50     2.374    -0.167     5.504     4.949    -0.509     0.059
      5.00     4.881    -0.206     6.380     4.881    -0.206     0.000
      7.50     7.477     0.030     7.516     4.833     0.143    -0.073
     10.00     9.985     0.720     7.148     4.600     0.677    -0.253
     12.50    12.292     1.954     5.103     4.302     1.267    -0.449
     15.00    13.959     4.106     2.661     4.031     1.817    -0.565

     ALPHA       CL        CD      CL/CD     X-C.P.

    -15.00   -12.795     6.183    -2.069     0.294
    -12.50   -10.896     7.643    -1.426     0.159
    -10.00    -8.592     8.773    -0.979     0.072
     -7.50    -6.432     8.427    -0.763     0.004
     -5.00    -4.307     6.781    -0.635    -0.042
     -2.50    -2.132     5.602    -0.381    -0.071
     -1.00    -0.841     5.302    -0.159    -0.074
      0.00     0.000     5.308     0.000     2.298
      1.00     0.841     5.302     0.159    -0.074
      2.50     2.132     5.602     0.381    -0.071
      5.00     4.307     6.781     0.635    -0.042
      7.50     6.432     8.427     0.763     0.004
     10.00     8.592     8.773     0.979     0.072
     12.50    10.896     7.643     1.426     0.159
     15.00    12.795     6.183     2.069     0.294
```

where you can get the input data to which the tables are related: MACH NO, ALTITUDE, SIDESLIP.

I have to create a 2-dimensional array (a table) for every group of data that have the same MACH NO, ALTITUDE and SIDESLIP.

Every time one of them changes I have to create a new array.

I am supposed to use regex to read the values next to the MACH NO, ALTITUDE and SIDESLIP ad check if they were changed but it seems to me a quite convoluted method. What would your approach be?

I was thinking of using Python.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : below is a piece of code which is doing the job. Since I decided to work on this topic to get more knowledge about the regexp, I end up a little bit frustrated since there is no regexp in the final code. Let me summarize below the different part of the parsing code with the hope that someone can help to use a regexp at the right place - I found only one place where the regexp could have been helpful but maybe there is other places where it could be the case. Feel free to comment.

1/ split the file into blocks by looking for the lines where there is the string '  FLIGHT CONDITIONS   ' - no regexp usefull I guess

2/split a block in two parts : first one with the hdr :
several lines with a format like the following line :
       MACH NUMBER = 0.67       REYNOLDS NU = 2.05E5 /M
Maybe this is a place here a regexp could have been helpful :
instead of splitting the line with ' ', how could a regexp have extracted from this line the useful information let say [('MACH NUMBER', 0.67), ('REYNOLDS NU', 2.05E5))

3/ merge the possibly splitted data array => I can't see if a regexp could have been usefull.

---

Here is a piece of code which is doing the job. I hope you can start from it to have the format you want. Let me explain it in a few words:

First step is to be able to split your file into blocks : blocks are separated with FLIGHT CONDITIONS.

Second step is to split a block into a hdr (where the details of the flight conditions are stored) and the raw data.

Details of the flight conditions are stored into a dct (hdr_dct) and the raw data are stored into a list (data_lst) with a data_hdr describing what is in the list.

```
import itertools
import sys

def parse_hdr(block) :
    """
    parsing the header of a block of data
    """
    parsed_hdr = {}
    for line in block :
        if '=' not in line :
            continue
        res = [e for e in line.split(' ') if len(e) >0] # remove white space
        match = False
        name = ''
        for e in res :
            if not match :
               if e == '=' :
                  match = True
               else :
                  name += e
            else :
               parsed_hdr[name] = float(e)
               name = ''
               match = False
    return parsed_hdr


def parse_data(block) :
    """
    parse the numerical data
    """
    hdr, res, block_id = [], [], -1
    for line in block :
        splitted_line = [e for e in line.split(' ') if len(e) > 0]
        if 'ALPHA' in splitted_line :
            hdr.extend(splitted_line)
            block_id += 1
            i_b = 0
        else :
            try :
                to_add = [float(e) for e in splitted_line]
            except :
                #print "skip : " + line
                sys.exc_clear()
                continue
            if block_id == 0 :
                res.append(to_add)
            else :
               res[i_b].extend(to_add)
            i_b += 1
    return hdr, res

def parse_block(block) :
"""
    parsing the data ofone block
"""
hdr_dct  = parse_hdr(block[:5])
data_hdr, data_lst = parse_data(block[6:])


def main() :
    block_limit ='    ******* FLIGHT CONDITIONS AND REFERENCE QUANTITIES *******'
    stt_data_lst = []
    end_data_lst = []

    with open('input.dat') as f :
       lines = f.readlines()
       for i_line, line in enumerate(lines) :
            if block_limit in line :
                stt_data_lst.append(i_line)

    end_data_lst = stt_data_lst[1:] + [-1]


    for stt, end in itertools.izip(stt_data_lst, end_data_lst) :
        parse_block([ee for ee in [e.strip() for e in lines[stt+1:end]] if len(ee) > 0])


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use something like

```
fid=fopen('yourfile');
A=fread(fid);
fclose(fid);

C=regexp(char(A'),'[\s ,]','split');
```

C will be a cell array consisting of strings (C{1} C{2} C{3} ...) obtained by breaking up the file by whitespace.  By keeping track of the index and applying str2num you should be able to get the data you need.

*edit*

Also, strcmp will work with C.  So for example if you want to find what cell index SIDESLIP occurs at you can do

```
n=find(strcmp(C,'SIDESLIP'));
```